# Vue v-bind conditional local file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a code like this :

```html
<img v-bind:src="user.photoUrl ? user.photoUrl : './assets/logo.png'">
```

But that directory access link renders just like a string.

Though it works with direct links like `https://website.com/imageName.png`

Is there any way to make it render like a directory call?

Comment: Please share any live demo for this ?

Comment: @C2486 I would like to, but my website runs on local server and I'm trying to access local directory, also, it works with direct links

Comment: i guess you can create the condition of this link within your code server directly, witch means you can do your test in the server side with  user.photoUrl if it's empty so put logo.png else put the original link.

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work by using it like so :

```html
<img v-bind:src="user.photoUrl ? user.photoUrl : require('./assets/logo.png')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img v-bind:src="user.photoUrl ? user.photoUrl : require('./assets/logo.png')">
```

or if you are using a bundler like webpack, you can do

```
import logo from './assets/logo.png'


<img v-bind:src="user.photoUrl ? user.photoUrl : {logo}">
```